# ListView scrollbar question

Tags: android, listview, scrollbar, customization

I was wondering if it is at all possible to customize the scroll bar inside of a populated listView. 
If it is, where are some good tutorials on how to do it?
ApiDemo scrollbar2.xml did not help me btw.

Comment: So I'm guessing this isn't possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following lines in android Theme:

```
<item name="scrollbarSize">10dip
<item name="scrollbarThumbHorizontal">@android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_horizontal
<item name="scrollbarThumbVertical">@android:drawable/scrollbar_handle_vertical
<item name="scrollbarTrackHorizontal">@android:drawable/scrollbar_horizontal
<item name="scrollbarTrackVertical">@android:drawable/scrollbar_vertical
```

So, you can try to override this in your custom theme.

Comment: I'm not sure where this is or what you mean..? Do I put this inside my ListView? or...? There is not a scrollbar attribute in ListView so ?

Comment: I meant [Applying Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)
But this will affect all scrollbars of applications.